# Which is base layer out of two tile layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I can't find docs about it, consider:

```
// base map
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/basemap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
  attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>,
    Data by <a href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);

// bike lanes
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.mapc.org/trailmap-onroad/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
  maxZoom: 17,
  minZoom: 9
}).addTo(map);
```

- So we added **two** tile layers to the map right? But which of the above two is set as a **base** layer now?
  Can a map have multiple base layers at once? (because I read somewhere base layers normally should be mutually exclusive).
- Extra: Can I change a base layer without using the layer control mechanism? (e.g. only programatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So we added two tile layers to the map right? But which of the above
>   two is set as a base layer now? Can a map have multiple base layers at
>   once? (because I read somewhere base layers normally should be
>   mutually exclusive).

Yes they are mutually exclusive in display so that means you can display only one layer at a time. It's not documented but the last layer added will become the base layer which is being displayed.

> Extra: Can I change a base layer without using the layer control
>   mechanism? (e.g. only programatically).

Yes you can using addLayer/removeLayer method.

```
map.removeLayer(base map layer name here);
map.addLayer(bike lane layer name here);
```

Comment: does the concept base layer actually exist for a map? or it is invented by the base layer control? because I can't find separate notion of base layer in the docs (apart from ones mentioned in layer control part)

Comment: There is no such explicit thing as base layer. It's named so because of layer control feature. You can add many tile layers you want and switch between them.

Comment: How does it distinguish between tile layer and layer consisting of only markers say? (e.g. not to confuse the z index). or there is no need to?

Comment: There is no need to until you want to do some action on layers. You can make use of bringToFront and bringToBack for that. There are different default z-index for different layer pane. http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-mappane

Answer (score 1):

> So we added two tile layers to the map right?

Yes.

> But which of the above two is set as a base layer now?

Leaflet has **no concept of base layer**, so the answer is "none".

> Can a map have multiple base layers at once? (because I read somewhere base layers normally should be mutually exclusive).

Depends on what you consider to be a "base layer".

I can, for example, have a map with several sets of opaque tiles, each of them being able to function as a base layer of a map, and make one of them semitransparent.

*Usually*, map frameworks *assume* that a tilelayer (or one tilelayer in a set of tilelayers) can be the *basic* information for your map, and in those circumstances, such set of tilelayers should be exclusive. Hence the wording of `L.Control.Layers`.

Leaflet does not constrain you to have a fully-opaque exclusive `L.TileLayer`. You can even have a Leaflet map without a single `L.TileLayer`. And of course, you can control visibility of your layers with `map.removeLayer(lyr)`, `map.addLayer(lyt)`, `layer.addTo(map)` and `layer.remove()`. Ultimately, the logic to control layer exclusivity (and opacity) is **up to you**.